# How to run route from other route function flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

are routes run only after clicking submit button? I want to run routes from other route function not by clicking submit button. I am doing like this because ajaxCall route only running function not rendering template

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/ajaxCall")
def home():
    # some code 
    # i want to call @app.route("/name") here
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route("/name")
def name():
    # some code 
    return render_template('name.html')


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=5002)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `redirect` function. Just redirect from `/ajaxCall` to `name` like this:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,send_file, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/ajaxCall")
    def home():
        # some code 
        # i want to call @app.route("/name") here
        return redirect('/name')
        # This will run your name route
        return render_template('home.html')


    @app.route("/name")
    def name():
        # some code 
        return render_template('name.html')


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=5002)
```

Comment: i tried with parameters like this`redirect(url_for('.name',par1=var1))` function run but still not loading the template I think this is coz url is not changing from `localhost:5002/` to `licalhost:5002/name` @Avad